# Azure: not able to browse to the URL

Tags: http, azure, certificate, azure-cloud-services, http-status-code-504

Azure has been acting very strange. Previously, all was fine until an update for my cloud service took more than the usual 20 minutes. I then decided to delete and redeploy, however not preserving the previous certificate.

So I repackaged and redeployed; however this time I was unable to connect to the web app via the usual *http://youraddrhere.cloudapp.net*. Every time I do that Chrome disappointingly tells me: *ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT*. When I remote into the cloud service and open the app from within IIS (i.e. its internal IP), it miraculously works! But there is no use if I am unable to expose my cloud service as a public site...

A quick check through my errors in the Event Viewer shows the following:
`A fatal error occurred when attempting to access the SSL server credential private key. The error code returned from the cryptographic module is 0x8009030d. The internal error state is 10001.` I have tried deleting, creating, uploading, deleting, recreating, and re-uploading numerous .cer and .pfx files but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong this time round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thereafter, my friend and a colleague RDPed into the Cloud Service and tried all sorts of methods to diagnose the issue, but saw none. There were no glaring issues in the Event Viewer, no endpoint binding conflicts in IIS, nothing wrong with the memory management. Overall, no problem at all.

His suggestion was then: to recreate a new Azure deployment project (`.ccproj`) from scratch, add in all the relevant roles, and attempt to republish. Initially I was skeptical, but deployment proved successful and as of now I am able to navigate to my cloud service both from within **and outside**.

I only attempted this when I had utterly no clue what the issue was-from past experiences however the Event Viewer will prove to be a great starting point for any of your headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the deployment and re-publish your cloud service.